# jQuery click event interrupts setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm creating script where I use AJAX from jQuery. I've got a problem, as on my website I've got hidden object. Moreover I use setInterval to frequently refresh a piece of my script. Everything works well, but until I click on link to set this hidden object to be visible. When I click on link and make object visible, setInterval stops refreshing page. This is my code to AJAX:

```
$(document).ready(setInterval(function() {  
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "score.php",
       success: function(html){
           $("#loadplace").hide().show().html(html);
       }
    });
    return false;}, 60000));
```

and this is code for link:

```
$('div#bar a#squad1').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('div#s1 table.events1').hide();       
    $('div#s1 table.index_players1').fadeIn();

});
$('div#bar a#events1').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('div#s1 table.index_players1').hide();
    $('div#s1 table.events1').fadeIn();
});
```

is there any solution in jQuery for my problem ?

P.S. I hope you understand what I wrote, I know that my English is not so good as I wish it to be.

Comment: your use of setInterval and dom ready isn't doing what you think it's doing. apparently you don't need the document ready at all.

Comment: Also, you're being overly specific in your jQuery selectors, when selecting by id, all you need is the id. `$("#squad1")` and `$("#events1")` Being more specific than that with an id is a performance hit.

Comment: What is the purpose of `$("#loadplace").hide().show()`? The `.hide()` seems superfluous to me. And if no other process touches `#loadplace` between two intervals then `show()` would also be redundant. Have you really waited 60seconds after clicking one of the two links to find out whether the interval action has stopped?